# Question on a Nullstellensatz proof

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm reading a proof of Nullstellensatz and there is a part I don't quite get. The proof starts by choosing an $f$ inside the ideal $I(V(J))$ of $k[x_1,...,x_n]$ where $k$ is an (algebraically closed) field and $J$ is also an ideal of the same polynomial ring. We then introduce a new variable $x_0$ and the new polynomial ring $k[x_0,x_1,...,x_n]$ and an ideal $K$ generated by the elements of $J$ and the element $1-x_0f$, inside the new ring. After that the proof states that $f$ is invertible in the new ring and that is the part I don't understand. Why is it invertible? Can somebody please explain this to me?

Comment: I highly doubt that the proof says "the new polynomial ring $k[x_0,x_1,...,x_n]$ generated by the elements of $J$ and the element $1-x_0f$".  Reread what it actually says and edit to reflect that if you're still confused.

Comment: Yes you are right, I forgot to add something. I'll edit it accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof surely states that $f$ is invertible in $k[x_0,\ldots,x_n]/K$. This is the point of introducing the auxiliary variable $x_0$. By modding out by $K$, you are setting $x_0=\frac{1}{f}$.

Comment: I'll check if that makes more sense but the proof does not speak about $k[x_0,...x_n]/K$ it clearly says $k[x_0,...x_n]$. Perhaps it's a mistake on the author's part.

Comment: Thank you, it makes much more sense now.